# Passing an object to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass an object to the function `flipIt(obj)`. I have the image id stored in a variable called `globe`.

When I pass `globe` to `flipIt()`, it isn't working because `globe` is a variable containing the image id and `flipIt()` needs an object.

I have tried `('#'+globe)` to make it `obj` but its is also not working:

```
flipIt('#'+globe);
```

**Function Definition is:**

```
function flipIt(obj) {
    console.log("value before Function status   " + status);
    alert('FlipIT Called' + obj);

    $(obj).css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
    $(obj).css("-webkit-transition","all 1.0s linear");
    $(obj).css("transform-style","preserve-3d");
    $(obj).css("transition","all 1.0s linear");
}
```

I tried by printing obj value... for variable it is printing id value instead it should print HTMLimage element.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var globe;

    /*   Reading the data from XML file*/
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "photos.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
                var path = $(this).attr('path');
                var width = $(this).attr('width');
                var height = $(this).attr('height');
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
                var longdesc = $(this).find('longdesc').text();
                var description = $(this).find('desc').text();
                $('#myImageFlow').prepend('<img src="'+path+'" id='+id+'  height="'+height+'"  width="'+ width+'" longdesc="'+longdesc+'" alt="'+alt+'"/>');
                imgArr[i] = description;
                i = i+1;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**XML File:**

```
<items id = "items">
   <item path="img/1_bankofamerica.jpg" width="300" height="360" id="id1" alt="img1" type="bitmapfile">
      <back>swf/backcard_0.swf </back>
      <longdesc>img/img1.png</longdesc>
      <desc>Decription about Image # 1 </desc>
   </item>
   <item path="img/2_harbourfront.jpg" width="300" height="360" id="id2" alt="img2" type="bitmapfile">
      <back>swf/backcard_1.swf </back>
      <longdesc>img/img2.png</longdesc>
      <desc>Decription about Image # 2 </desc>
   </item>
   <item path="img/2_harbourfront3.jpg" width="300" height="360" id="id3" alt="img3" type="bitmapfile">
      <back>swf/backcard_2.swf </back>
      <longdesc>img/img3.png</longdesc>
      <desc>Decription about Image # 3 </desc>
   </item>
   <item path="img/3_harbourfront.jpg" width="300" height="360" id="id4" alt="img4" type="bitmapfile">
      <back>swf/backcard_3.swf </back>
      <longdesc>img/img4.png</longdesc>
      <desc>Decription about Image # 4 </desc>
   </item>
   <item path="img/5_lighthouse.jpg" width="300" height="360" id="id5" alt="img5" type="bitmapfile">
      <back>swf/backcard_4.swf </back>
      <longdesc>img/img5.png</longdesc>
      <desc>Decription about Image # 5 </desc>
   </item>
</items>
```

Comment: I would say, pass `$('#'+globe)`, but I see you're already doing this inside the `flipIt` function. Why do you access `globe` again in the `flipIt` function if you want to pass it?

Comment: was just checking globe.. i am not accessing globe inside function

Comment: What does this mean? "i have obj value stored in a variable 'globe'" You're using globe as if it's a string not an object.

Comment: show content of globe, and show the HTML code that contains the element with that id..

Comment: try to put it in a global variable

Comment: object value means i have image id stored in a variable . and i want to pass image object to function.

Answer (score 3):

Asuming `globe` is a string containing the `id` of the element you want to select (not prefixed with `#`), you'll need to transform it into a jQuery object before passing it to your function:

```
flipIt($('#'+globe));
```

Then, you don't need to wrap another `$()` around it inside the `flipIt` function, because it's already an object. So inside the function, just do:

```
obj.css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
...
```

Next, I guess you want to declare `globe` in the global scope. Now you're declaring it in the scope of the document ready function. So put it outside:

```
var globe;

$(document).ready(function () {
    // document ready
});
```

Also the document ready has a shorter notation:

```
$(function() {
    // document ready
});
```